# Nvidia-utils "failed to prepare transaction" error with pacman

Tags: nvidia, manjaro, pacman

I'm new to arch-based distros and I've been using Manjaro (and pacman directly from the terminal without things like pamac) for 1 month or so with the same nvidia graphics card (gtx 1660 super) and I've never seen this error in any package:

```
looking for conflicting packages...
error: failed to prepare transaction (could not satisfy dependencies)
:: installing nvidia-utils (460.80-1) breaks dependency 'nvidia-utils=460.73.01' required by linux59-nvidia
```

I've seen that this error could happen with experimental packages and know the solution is just use another more stable package but I don't know what to do with what looks like an important package.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I remember these issues back from when I used to use Manjaro myself. When experiencing this issue, you need to remove the conflicting package before being able to upgrade to the next one. I don't know if you still need help but you can follow the steps below if you still have these issues.

1. Let's say you use kernel `5.8`: you need to remove the Nvidia drivers using `sudo pacman -R linux58-nvidia-460xx nvidia-460xx-utils linux58-nvidia-460xx`.
2. Update the kernel to the version you want to use (e.g. `5.9`).
3. If you prefer using a GUI, you go to `System Settings` > [`Hardware Configuration`](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QEmbc.png) (click on the link to view what screen I am talking about) and select the drivers you want installed. If you prefer the CLI, you write this `sudo pacman -Sy linux59-nvidia-460xx nvidia-460xx-utils linux59-nvidia-460xx`.
4. Reboot.